Accessing original object (one being serialized / validated) from validators, computed_field(), etc
I use pydantic in a FastAPI project to serialize SQLAlchemy entity objects, and I need to access the original entity object in @computed_field methods and validators in order to access data from relationships (which are not supposed to be themselves serialized).
This is what I tried so far:
    def __init__(__pydantic_self__, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print(kwargs)  # not called at all

    @model_validator(mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def validate_model(cls, values):
        # 'values' contains the desired entity object, but there is no access to the model instance,
        # so I can't save it for future use

    @computed_field
    @property
    def extra_prop(self) -> bool:
        # no access to the entity object

    def model_post_init(self, ctx):
        print(ctx)  # always None

Is there any supported way to do this, or a workaround known to work?

I don't know if there is a direct way to get that from pydantic model, but you can use following workaround
from typing import Annotated, Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, PlainValidator, TypeAdapter


class Test(BaseModel):
    name: str
    original_values: Annotated[dict[str, Any], Field(exclude=True)] = {}


def validate(values: dict[str, Any]) -> Test:
    return Test(name=values["name"], original_values=values)


ValidatedTest = TypeAdapter(Annotated[Test, PlainValidator(validate)])

values = {"name": "test", "other_data": "data"}
test = ValidatedTest.validate_python(values)
print(test.original_values)


